# Undefined Reference when using a C++ library function

Tags: c++, static-libraries, codeblocks

Using Code::Blocks and the GNU GCC compiler, I went along and made my own library:

```
//main.cpp (Library)
int SampleAddInt(int i1, int i2)
{
    return i1 + i2;
}
```

Compiled it to a .a file. I then made a separate project to test the library function with. Made sure I linked it correctly in the Build Options. Here's my code using it in my project:

```
//main.cpp (Test Project)
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

//Declaration of function from library
int SampleAddInt(int i1, int i2);

int main(){
    int x = SampleAddInt(2, 4);
    cout << x << "test" << endl;
}
```

Got this error when trying to compile my Test Project:

> main.cpp|9|undefined reference to `SampleAddInt(int, int)'|

For some reason it can't seem to find this function. I then wrapped extern "C" { ... } around the declaration in my Test Project main.cpp source and it built correctly.

Why, when my library was compiled from a main.cpp source, do I need to use extern "C" for my library to work with my Test Project? And why when I don't use extern "C", does the compiler tell me that the function is an undefined reference?

Comment: Did you accidentally compile the library file using `gcc` instead of `g++` maybe?

Comment: I used the Code::Blocks IDE. When I was setting up the IDE it asked me which compiler to use and I chose the GNU GCC compiler. Is this not correct? I recall reading that the GNU GCC compiler and compile both C and C++. It's the only one that's detected on my system.

Comment: It's the same compiler, correct, but you have to be sure to compile c++ files in c++ mode. Usually this is the default if `g++` is used. You should see the commandline command that are used in the console window of codeblocks.

Comment: Ah you're right, it's using mingw32-gcc.exe. How do I switch this so .cpp files will automatically get compiled using mingw32-g++.exe ?

Comment: In toolchain executables tab in my global compiler settings, it shows that the C++ compiler is set to mingw32-g++.exe. Why is this using gcc still?

Comment: It's maybe a problem with your [project settings](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html). Sorry I don't have the time right now to research that further for you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

The problem was it had to do with Code::Blocks.

It was using the gcc compiler instead of g++ so I was forced to use extern "C" if I wanted to run any of my library code.

To fix this I right clicked main.cpp, clicked Properties, and changed the variable from "CC" to "CPP" and it now compiles with g++.